# Should I block ?limit=all

Tags: php, catalog

Suppose you have a store with `10.000 products`. You page per 30 products, have filters and search.

Suppose someone has bad intent and they request this page several times all with the `?limit=all` param. This is very ***resource intensive + almost certain*** someone with ill intent

**Question**: Should I block ?limit=all? And if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably a good idea. You will be happy to hear that it is configurable.

Set "Allow All Products per Page" to "No" in *System > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend*

Now "All" is not shown in the limit dropdown anymore, and what's more important, will not work as limit parameter as well. Magento only allows parameter values that are actually available by configuration.